# Why does my linear regression model fail if I don't center input data?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, linear-regression

I have simple linear regression model, where the independent variable is *years* (1970-present). When I center the input data around zero (i.e. subtract the mean from x) then my model runs fine and I get best-fit-line. But if I don't center the data, the model has infinite loss:

```py
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])

model.compile(
    tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.001, momentum=0.9),
    loss='mse'
)

model_history = model.fit(
    x, # If we change this to `x - x.mean()` then we no longer get nan\inf loss
    y,
    epochs=200
)
```

```sh
Epoch 1/200
6/6 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: inf     
Epoch 2/200
6/6 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 3/200
6/6 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 4/200
6/6 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan
.
.
.
```

I would have expected the model to be slower or maybe not as accurate, but why does it completely break altogether?

Edit: [this is what the data looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luCkk.png)

Comment: Possibly the value of the learning rate is (still) too big so that you are getting away from the global minimum during the SGD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regression with ANNs are a bit tricky. You see nan loss values because your gradients have exploded. That's because **outputs don't have an upper bound**. Also why do you use momentum?

You can try:

- Reducing learning rate
- Changing to adam optimizer

Comment: It was indeed a learning rate issue. But what I don't understand is why the very first epoch already has infinite loss. If the learning rate affects the loss value (on the first iteration), then that means that the TensorFlow algorithm computes backprop/update step before it calculates the loss?

Comment: You measure how -bad- your model is with loss function. A predicted y_hat value is required in order to calculate loss. Also having inf MSE could be because the **prediction** tended to infinity.